# Mui radio button styling - Different coloured outer and inner circle

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, radio-button

I have a requirement to make a [MUI radio button](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-radio-button/) that has a different outer ring colour than the selected inner fill colour.

I have looked through the official docs but it seems that they either only accommodate customising the colour on a whole, or it is possible to customise the entire radio with other custom icons passed into the element itself.

Am I missing something obvious about styling in the manner I wish, or is it just a big job to do something so simple?

Answer (score 1):

I could simulate different colors for the ring and inner fill using `:after` and `:before` like this for green border and red inner fill:

```
  <Radio
    {...controlProps("e")}
    sx={{
      color: "green",
      "&.Mui-checked": {
        position: "relative",
        "&::before": {
          content: '""',
          position: "absolute",
          top: "50%",
          left: "50%",
          transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
          width: "10px",
          height: "10px",
          borderRadius: "50%",
          backgroundColor: "white"
        },
        "&::after": {
          content: '""',
          position: "absolute",
          top: "50%",
          left: "50%",
          transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
          width: "10px",
          height: "10px",
          borderRadius: "50%",
          backgroundColor: "red",
          opacity: 1,
          borderColor:"red"
        },
        "&.Mui-checked::after": {
          opacity: 1
        }
      }
    }}
  />
```